# Фильтрация пользователей по полям из профиля, Django

Tags: django

День добрый.
Есть стандартный пользователь из auth.User. Есть профиль с полем City. Мне надо получить список пользователей из города Х.

```
users = User.objects.filter(что_то.City=X)
```

Такое возможно, или надо брать всех пользователей и проверять профиль каждого исключая его из общего списка при несовпадении. Подскажите как быть ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример

```
users = User.objects.filter(userprofile__city='odessa')
```